# excluding some classes from web-inf/classes

Tags: gwt, maven-2, maven-war-plugin

I use maven-war-plugin to build WAR, and I need to exclude several WAR classes from web-inf/classes (that's GWT classes, they shouldn't get to server deployment).

How can I do it in maven?
I tried "warSourceExcludes", "packagingExcludes" with no success.

Any simple and creative solution in maven is acceptable, I need it for a test project.

thanks

Comment: I really believe GWT development with Maven should involve at least 2 modules: `client` and `server`; and possibly a third `shared` module, which both `client` and `server` depend on. You'd use gwt-maven-plugin  either in `client` (with the maven-assembly-plugin to produce a ZIP used as a war overlay in `server`), or in `server` (which would then depend on `client` with scope=provided so that `client.jar` isn't included in the war; I guess you could also put `client` as a dependency of gwt-maven-plugin instead)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245953/excluding-some-classes-from-web-inf-classes

Answer (score 5):

Configuring `packagingExcludes` for the `maven-war-plugin` works for me:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**</packagingExcludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```